# can not find symbol Authentication Exception in Stripe library

Tags: java, android, maven, stripe-payments, apklib

I am trying to generate an apklib using mvn clean install. The stripe library can be built independently but with mvn clean install it gives the following error:

```
/Stripe.java:[87,23] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class AuthenticationException
[ERROR] location: class com.stripe.android.Stripe
```

I am new to maven and not sure why I am still able to build using eclipse build tools.
Please help.

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.stripe.android</groupId>
    <artifactId>stripe</artifactId>
    <name>Android-Stripe</name>
    <packaging>apklib</packaging>
    <version>2.4.1</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>4.1.1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
            <version>r6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration><sdk><platform>19</platform></sdk></configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>../checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>checkstyle</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```